# Jquery deserialize(data) is not working with % data

Tags: javascript

I am serializing the data like below

```js
var data = $('#form').find("input,select").serialize();
data = data + "&cols=" + JSON.stringify(Columns);
```

see below data getting like

```js
myformdata=data&cols={"name":"dummyuser %*"}
```

when I try to perform below code it is giving the error which was shown in  this

[image: screenshot]

```js
myform.find("input,select").not(groupByAndSortByColumns.find("input,select")).deserialize(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests `URL malformed at decodeURIComponent`, the data that your `deserialize` function is trying to decode is malformed. You should use `encodeURIComponent` to encode your data before deserializing like this:

```js
myform.find("input,select").not(groupByAndSortByColumns.find("input,select")).deserialize(encodeURIComponent(data));
```

Comment: Which `deserialize` function are you using?